# UDAF in Spark with multiple input columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I am trying to develop a user defined aggregate function that computes a linear regression on a row of numbers. I have successfully done a UDAF that calculates confidence intervals of means (with a lot trial and error and SO!).

Here's what actually runs for me already:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.{MutableAggregationBuffer, UserDefinedAggregateFunction}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, DoubleType, LongType, DataType, ArrayType}

case class RegressionData(intercept: Double, slope: Double)

class Regression  {

  import org.apache.commons.math3.stat.regression.SimpleRegression

  def roundAt(p: Int)(n: Double): Double = { val s = math pow (10, p); (math round n * s) / s }

  def getRegression(data: List[Long]): RegressionData = {
    val regression: SimpleRegression  = new SimpleRegression()
    data.view.zipWithIndex.foreach { d =>
        regression.addData(d._2.toDouble, d._1.toDouble)
    }

    RegressionData(roundAt(3)(regression.getIntercept()), roundAt(3)(regression.getSlope()))
  }
}


class UDAFRegression extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction {

  import java.util.ArrayList

  def deterministic = true

  def inputSchema: StructType =
    new StructType().add("units", LongType)

  def bufferSchema: StructType =
    new StructType().add("buff", ArrayType(LongType))


  def dataType: DataType =
    new StructType()
      .add("intercept", DoubleType)
      .add("slope", DoubleType)

  def initialize(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer) = {
    buffer.update(0, new ArrayList[Long]())
  }

  def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row) = {
    val longList: ArrayList[Long]  = new ArrayList[Long](buffer.getList(0))
    longList.add(input.getLong(0));
    buffer.update(0, longList);

  }

  def merge(buffer1: MutableAggregationBuffer, buffer2: Row) = {
    val longList: ArrayList[Long] = new ArrayList[Long](buffer1.getList(0))
    longList.addAll(buffer2.getList(0))

    buffer1.update(0, longList)
  }


  def evaluate(buffer: Row) = {
    import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
    val list = buffer.getList(0).asScala.toList
    val regression = new Regression
    regression.getRegression(list)
  }
}
```

However the datasets do not come in order, which is obviously very important here. Hence instead of `regression($"longValue")` I need to a second param `regression($"longValue", $"created_day")`. `created_day` is a `sql.types.DateType`.

I am pretty confused by DataTypes, StructTypes and what-not and due to the lack of examples on the web, I got stuck w/ my trial and order attempts here.

#### What would my `bufferSchema` look like?

Are those StructTypes overhead in my case? Wouldn't a (mutable) `Map` just do? Is `MapType` actually immutable and isn't this rather pointless to be a buffer type?

#### What would my `inputSchema` look like?

Does this have to match the type I retrieve in `update()` via in my case `input.getLong(0)`?

#### Is there a standard way how to reset the buffer in `initialize()`

I have seen `buffer.update(0, 0.0)` (when it contains Doubles, obviously), `buffer(0) = new WhatEver()` and I think even `buffer = Nil`. Does any of these make a difference?

#### How to update data?

The example above seems over complicated. I was expecting to be able to do sth. like `buffer += input.getLong(0) -> input.getDate(1)`.
Can I expect to access the input this way

#### How to merge data?

Can I just leave the function block empty like
`def merge(…) = {}`?

The challenge to sort that buffer in `evaluate()` is sth. I should be able to figure out, although I am still interested in the most elegant ways of how you guys do this (in a fraction of the time).

#### Bonus question: What role does `dataType` play?

I return a case class, not the `StructType` as defined in `dataType` which does not seem to be an issue. Or is it working since it happens to match my case class?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will clear things up.

The `UDAF APIs` work on `DataFrame` `Columns`. Everything you are doing has to get serialized just like all the other `Columns` in the `DataFrame`. As you note, the only support `MapType` is immutable, because this is the only thing you can put in a `Column`. With immutable collections, you just create a new collection that contains the old collection plus a value:

```
var map = Map[Long,Long]()
map = map + (0L -> 1234L)
map = map + (1L -> 4567L)
```

Yes, just like working with any `DataFrame`, your types have to match. Do `buffer.getInt(0)` when there's really a `LongType` there is going to be a problem.

There's no standard way to reset the buffer because other than whatever makes sense for your data type / use case. Maybe zero is actually last month's balanace; maybe zero is a running average from another dataset; maybe zero is an `null` or an empty string or maybe zero is really zero.

`merge` is an optimization that only happens in certain circumstances, if I remember correctly -- a way to sub-total that the SQL optimization may use if the circumstances warrant it. I just use the same function I use for `update`.

A `case class` will automatically get converted to the appropriate schema, so for the bonus question the answer is yes, it's because the schemas match. Change the `dataType` to not match, you will get an error.

Comment: I'll try to use that when give it another shot, maybe it's simpler than it looks to me!

Comment: It's my understanding that merge adds the current buffer to the output row of another instance. You can only use your update function for merge if an output row could be used as an input row, which it could be for sum, but not for count. Columns have to match in meaning, number and type.